# Acessing to a base subobject and virtual specifier c++

Tags: c++, class, oop

I'm trying to understand what exactly purpose of a virtual specifier in base class. As said in the c++14 working draft we have:

> For each distinct base class that is specified virtual, the most
>   derived  object shall contain a single base class subobject of that
>   type.

From this quote I'm assume that if we create an instance `c` of class `C` which is a derived class for `A` and `B` we're create an objects of `A` and `B` implicitly.

**Question:** How can I access to an instances of a base classes via an instance of derived class?

Comment: The final question seems unrelated to the introduction.

Comment: You cannot access inherited methods across instances unless they are public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An object of class `struct C : A, B {};` contains two base subobjects, one of type `A` and one of type `B`. You can access them "directly":

```
void foo(A &);
void bar(B &);

C c;
foo(c);   // accesses the A-subobject
bar(c);   // accesses the B-subobject
```

You can also say `static_cast<A&>(c)` and `static_cast<B&>(c)` explicitly, though this is not often needed. You sometimes need to disambiguate names, though:

```
struct A { void f(); };
struct B { void f(); };
struct C : A, B { void f(); };

C c;

c.f();     // calls the member "f" of C
c.A::f();  // calls the member "f" of the A-base subobject of c
c.B::f();  // calls the member "f" of the B-base subobject of c
```

All this is not really related to the concept of *virtual inheritance*, which says that there is only relevant base subobject, even if it is referred to through multiple distinct inheritances:

```
struct V {};
struct A : virtual V {};
struct B : virtual V {};
struct C : A, B {};
```

In this last example, an object `C c` has only *one* base subobject of type `V`, not two, and the `V`-base subobjects of the `A`- and `B`-base subobjects of `c` see the *same* `V` base subobject. The virtual base is "shared" across the inheritance hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

`virtual` specifier is not related to accessing base sub-object, rather number of base sub-object in derived object. You can access base sub-object even if the base is not virtual. `virtual` is here to solve other problems like [diamond inheritance problem](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html)